# Is it possible to make a bookmark in google chrome that doesn't go to the page, just fills URL only?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I want to make something that functions exactly like a bookmark, but doesn't go to the page. Just fills in the URL only. Is anyone aware of a way to do this? The reason I want to do this is that the page doesn't work on its own, it needs information after the bookmark, to go to the right page.

Example: I want to use the wall street journal to do cursory research on stocks.
I want a bookmark to fill in the URL: https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/

That page doesn't exist on its own, but if you add a ticker to the end of the URL, it will go to that stock. If I want to see Apple's stock info, I would simply add "AAPL" to that URL, then click enter, and it would go to the Apple stock info page.

Comment: Instead of manually appending something to this one "bookmark", why not create a separate one for each URL like .../AAPL?

Comment: There are simply too many tickers that I would be interested in tracking. There would be hundreds or more bookmarks. It makes more sense to manually enter the tickers.

Answer (score 0):

An easier alternative would be to create a custom search engine within Chrome by going into the settings, selecting "Manage search engines" and then adding one with "Add" option.

Then use the following:

- Search engine: `WSJ Stocks`
- Keyword: `stocks`
- URL: `https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/%s`

Now whenever you type `stocks AAPL` into Chrome and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, Chrome will take you to https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/AAPL

You could always replace `stocks` with something shorter (say `s`) if this search is something you're going to be doing a lot.

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Thank you Richard. I just added this search engine to my browser and it works exactly the way I wanted.

Comment: @Jacob You’re welcome. Don’t forget to click on the tick next to the answer to mark it as answered :)